# Web API POST - giving 500 error in postman - how to resolve?

Tags: asp.net-core, http-post, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to use postman to test my POST method, however I am getting a 500 error and when called in my api's try catch method it fail the try and throws the error but im not sure why or how to find out.

I would like to enter any dummy data into my 'message_Chain' and i have copied the code I have below, can anyone please tell me what I have done wrong? Im very new to using web apis and postman so im not sure how to track where it goes wrong myself.

EDIT - also how do I display more details of what the 500 error actually is in postman so i can see why is it been thrown?

```
// POST: api/Message_Chain
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754.
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Message_Chain>> PostMessage_Chain(Message_Chain message_Chain)
        {
            _context.Message_Chain.Add(message_Chain);
            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                if (Message_ChainExists(message_Chain.MessageChainId))
                {
                    return Conflict();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return CreatedAtAction("GetMessage_Chain", new { id = message_Chain.MessageChainId }, message_Chain);
        }

public class Message_Chain
    {
        [Key]
        public int MessageChainId { get; set; }
        public int MessageSubjectId { get; set; }
        public string MessageBody { get; set; }
        public int SentFromId { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
        public Message_Subject Message_Subject { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Colleague_Message> Colleague_Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is what I have put in postman,

```
POST > http://<my url>/api/Message_Chain
BODY > JSON
{
    "messageChainId": 10,
    "messageSubjectId": 10,
    "messageBody": "Testing my post to message chain method from postman",
    "sentFromId": 1000001,
    "dateTime": "2020-11-05T12:15:00"
}
```

Comment: Please check the error‘s type in the console. Because I cannot reproduce the error in this code.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Message_Chain>> PostMessage_Chain([FromBody] Message_Chain message_Chain)
    {
        _context.Message_Chain.Add(message_Chain);
        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            if (Message_ChainExists(message_Chain.MessageChainId))
            {
                return Conflict();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return CreatedAtAction("GetMessage_Chain", new { id = message_Chain.MessageChainId }, message_Chain);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, no luck unfortunately I get the same error